# Eslint error ,,couldn't find the config "next/core-web-vitals" to extend from"

Tags: reactjs, next.js, frontend, eslint, lint

After running command ,,npm run lint" (lint stands for ,,next lint"), I get error.:

```
Failed to load config "next/core-web-vitals" to extend from.
Referenced from: /Users/filiptaticek/Desktop/.eslintrc.json
```

I don't have any .eslintrc.json file on my Desktop and I have this issue even when I make a new NextJS project.

I have .eslintrc.json in my directory with content:

```
{
 "extends": "next/core-web-vitals"
}
```

And then .eslintrc.js with configuration for Eslint. Any thoughts how to repair it please? Nothing on Stack overflow did help.

Comment: You should only have one ESLint config file. Merge `.eslintrc.json` and `.eslintrc.js` into a single file at the root of your project.

Comment: Thank you @juliomalves, but I do have only .eslintrc.js. The issue is that from some reason the code searches for .eslintrc.json file on my desktop and it cannot find it. I get this issue with any NEXT project I make.

Answer (score 0):

**The solution**: The .eslintrc.json is hidden by default, since it starts with an dot. Due to this it is not visible on my desktop neither finder, but you have to delete and find it through command line.